# Table won't wrap down

Tags: html, css

I have a collection of 3 divs, two of them with tables, the configuration should be like this:

[image: coorect]

But, whenever the top left div is smaller than the left, this happens:

[image: error]

I tried to put `clear: both` in the last div and though it worked, i have a floating sidebar outside the div that interfieres with the height of the break.

I tried to replicate the problem in jsfiddle but it works alright there

http://jsfiddle.net/kumiau/5hyLf/1/

I can't seem to find the problem. To see it, please go to http://franigfilters.com/wordpress/catalog/catalogo.php click on "BUSCAR REFERENCIA FRANIG" and input "HCACP2" in the search field.

Thank you

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: If the text being displayed in the table cannot physically be any thinner, then of course it's going to overflow.  In this situation the containing div needs to be able to cope with that table being too big, but using something like CSS `overflow`

Comment: Do you need to send "posicion" class named div to bottom?

Comment: Not "posicion", I need to move to the bottom "specs".

Answer (score -1):

In Your css try changing this line:

```
body.catalogo #divresultado .equivalencias {
  width: 60%;
  float: right;
}
```